# Animate buttons sliding in

Tags: java, libgdx, android, animation, gui

I am developing my first libGDX game.

I want to animate the buttons on the stage, so they transition into view instead of just popping into appearance. For example, each button should slide in from the left, starting from the button at the bottom and progressing up the stack, like in this gif:

[image: Button animation]

I don't understand how this can be done. How would I go about animating buttons this way?